# java transaction management - propagation

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
public void jasperToInvoice1(BigDecimal generateNo) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException, JRException{
    List<TInvoiceSummary> invoices = invoiceSummaryRepository.findListSummary(generateNo) ;
    Connection connection =  dataSource.getConnection() ;
    if (invoices.size() > 0) {
        int i = 1 ;
        for(TInvoiceSummary invoice : invoices) {
            jasperConvert.jInvoicePdf(invoice,connection);
            invoice.setIsPdf(true);

            em.merge(invoice) ;
            if(i % batchSize == 0) {
                em.flush();
                em.clear();
            }
            i++ ;
        }
    }
}
```

I want to ask something about spring transactional propagation. Let's say I want to insert 10.000 rows into my DB. When I insert to DB I want to flush every 100 record. Is it possible to select the record while the process is still running? and how to do that?

please let me know how to do that and if someone have an alternative way to do something like this.

Thanks

Comment: You won't be able to query anything until the current transaction is commited

Comment: If your transaction related to 2-phase commit, then `flush()` doesn't actually commit your transaction, until you explicitly call `commit()`. If it is not related to 2-phase commit, then after `flush()` called, data should be visible and you can query your data.

Comment: where do I commit() method ? there is no function about commit in em (EntityManager) @AtaurRahmanMunna

Comment: `em.getTransaction().commit();`

Comment: if I call method em.getTransaction().commit() ;  I got exception 

[code]Fatal error :java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not allowed to create transaction on shared EntityManager - use Spring transactions or EJB CMT instead[/code]

Comment: `@Transactional` annotation belongs to which ?? Spring or something else? Use Spring component & also I guess your transactional configure is not ok.

Comment: I'm use spring boot wt base annotation, so my configuration is auto. can you give me example how to configure this transaction management in spring boot ? thx @AtaurRahmanMunna